# Binary System with Sigma Summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binary

Let 100110101 be a number from the binary system with the digits being $$ 
b_i \in \left\{0,1\right\}
$$ If we calculate this number into the decimal system, the result is 309.
What formula can be used to do this kind of calculation?

The answer:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} b_i2^i
$$

Can someone help me understand how this formula can be used for this calculation?

Comment: The same way as for example $5234=5\cdot 10^3+2\cdot 10^2+3\cdot10+4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave $B=100110101$ as an example, which amounts to saying:
$$
\begin{align}
b_0&=1\text{ (least significant digit)}\\
b_1&=0\\
b_2&=1\\
b_3&=0\\
b_4&=1\\
b_5&=1\\
b_6&=0\\
b_7&=0\\
b_5&=1
\end{align}
$$
and thus:
$$
\begin{align}
B&=\sum_{i=0}^{9-1}b_i 2^i\\
&=b_0\cdot 2^0+b_1\cdot 2^1+...+b_8\cdot2^8\\
&=1\cdot 1+0\cdot 2+1\cdot 4+0\cdot 8+1\cdot 16+1\cdot 32+0\cdot 64+0\cdot 128+1\cdot 256\\
&=309
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I could not get my head wrapped around how to use =100110101 with ∈{0,1} With your input, it now makes sense. Thank you!